# Using a Toggle to change the layout of a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now I have a page layout that is styled with CSS.

On this page there is a toggle that should switch between 2 pages with different content and CSS content (for example there are 2 boxes either side of the toggle that change color dependant on what is selected)

What is the best way to handle this?

Right now I've found a onClick event that should do it like a button, but it doesn't seem to work at all

```
 changeText(){
    var pageText=document.getElementByID("page1");
    if (pageText.innerHTML === "Some text"){
    pageText.innerHTML = "Swapped Text";
    } else {
    pageTxt.innerHTML = "Some text"
    }
```

Update:

I know have this code to change the layout:

```
function changePage(){
  var page1 = document.getElementById("firstpage");
  var page2 = document.getElementById("secondpage");

  page1.style.display = (page1?.style.display === 'none')? 'block': 'none';
  page2.style.display = (page1?.style.display === 'none')? 'block': 'none';
```

However, when I use a onClick, nothing happens at all

```
<label class=" switch" onclick= "changePage()">
    <input type="checkbox" >
    <span class="slider round" ></span>
  </label>
```

I've tried the onClick in several locations there and I have also added a basic button to test it and that also does nothing

Comment: "some text" is not the same string as "Some text"; JavaScript string comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: As well as the above typo, please don't directly try to match the `innerHTML`, it will cause you a world of problems. Store a state variable in JS (a boolean if you only have 2 states) and set the content based on that.

Comment: Apologies the typo was one I made on this post, the original code didn't have it

Comment: The function is called `getElementById` with a lower case `d`

Comment: Please read [ask], provide a [mcve], and a description more detailed that [doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way can be to have the content of pages inside two div

and write a function that toggle visibility for different pages based on visibility of other pages

```js
function changePage() {
    var page1 = document.getElementById("page1");
    var page2 = document.getElementById("page2");
    
    page1.style.display = (page1.style.display === 'none') ? 'block': 'none';
    page2.style.display = (page1.style.display === 'none') ? 'block': 'none';
    
}
```

```css
#page1 {
  display: block;
}

#page2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1">
  the content of page1
</div>

<div id="page2">
  the content of page2
</div>

<button onClick="changePage()">change page</button>
```

with a checkbox it can look like

```js
function changePage() {
  var page1 = document.getElementById("page1");
  var page2 = document.getElementById("page2");

  page1.style.display = (page1.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
  page2.style.display = (page1.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';

}
```

```css
#page1 {
  display: block;
}

#page2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1">
  the content of page1
</div>

<div id="page2">
  the content of page2
</div>

<label class=" switch" onclick="changePage()">
    <input type="checkbox" >
    <span class="slider round" ></span>
  </label>
```

Comment: I have implemented this like your answer and I cannot get a button to change the page at all

Comment: what do you mean by "cannot get a button" you want another mecanism ? or you button doesn't call the function ?

Comment: Sorry, phrased that wrong, yea the button doesn't call the function

Comment: i saw the edit on your main post. I edited my reply to include a checkbox instead of a button. do you see that you write `page1?.` instead of `page1.` ? if it doesn't solve your issue don't hesitate to include a snippet to your main post to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: The ? was a remnant from using this in a Typescript file first, I've added this a  <script> section in the HTML and edited it to match your code, still nothing

Answer (score -1):

You can use selectors to get to your HTML elements :

```js
const page = document.querySelector("#page")

let dark = false

toggleLayout = () => {
  dark = !dark
  page.classList = dark ? "dark" : "light"
}
```

```css
.light {
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: silver;
  color: black;
}

.dark {
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: silver;
  background-color: black;
}

.layout3 {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #FF5000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleLayout()">Change layout</button>
<div id="page" class="light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare bibendum enim rutrum rutrum. Proin suscipit leo ut turpis dignissim, ut laoreet neque volutpat. Ut vulputate rhoncus orci, eget interdum est scelerisque at. Integer non orci luctus, porta augue ac, semper libero. Proin nulla elit, tincidunt in neque vitae, luctus placerat lectus. Sed a mattis magna, eu lacinia purus. Nulla commodo tortor et pulvinar facilisis. Donec vulputate lectus eget tellus pellentesque, vitae tincidunt odio vulputate.

In maximus, turpis sed mollis luctus, justo nibh auctor nisi, quis ultrices ante nulla a eros. Curabitur commodo magna nulla. Nam risus metus, convallis in accumsan sit amet, dapibus vitae augue. Nulla a tortor at lectus porta iaculis sit amet eu mauris. Donec commodo, tortor eget viverra semper, mauris diam mollis sapien, feugiat interdum sem tellus ut velit. Duis quis est dictum ligula pharetra aliquam vitae in ante. Etiam eu commodo ex, suscipit convallis nisi. Nullam gravida ut est quis blandit. Etiam gravida erat viverra rutrum dictum. Duis hendrerit diam eget justo sodales commodo. Nam scelerisque ut justo vitae semper. Etiam blandit nisl tellus, a vestibulum ante imperdiet id. Proin quis nibh neque. Phasellus tempus felis quam, nec tincidunt metus placerat dictum. Nam nulla nulla, accumsan ultrices mauris a, consectetur elementum ipsum. Aenean ullamcorper ipsum et dui pharetra sodales.

Sed et egestas magna. Fusce sagittis gravida est cursus dapibus. Praesent sapien nunc, dignissim sit amet convallis a, hendrerit vel neque. Donec dapibus justo at nunc cursus, non tristique enim venenatis. Donec eu nulla eget ex ultricies vestibulum sed ut dui. Nullam augue sapien, porttitor vel elit efficitur, placerat laoreet urna. Donec aliquam, urna sit amet laoreet tristique, dui dolor porttitor felis, sit amet faucibus tortor enim at tellus. Praesent congue vitae est vel facilisis.

Maecenas tincidunt pharetra tortor et lobortis. Nunc sed lorem vitae arcu finibus aliquet sed in augue. Donec consequat neque ac mi malesuada fringilla. Nullam sagittis dignissim turpis, sed gravida diam rhoncus tincidunt. Sed sollicitudin, tortor eu fringilla tincidunt, lectus magna tempor augue, quis condimentum magna eros tincidunt lectus. Nunc ac massa sit amet nulla dapibus tristique. Nulla sodales nec purus quis semper. In convallis placerat ex ut cursus. Morbi vehicula egestas dolor vitae maximus.

Morbi eu erat congue, faucibus odio id, ultrices ipsum. Morbi id nunc cursus, porttitor ligula id, commodo magna. Fusce egestas vitae est sed hendrerit. Duis sit amet nulla cursus, porta libero efficitur, mattis eros. Integer consequat purus blandit, varius arcu sed, placerat nisl. Nulla nec sem nisi. Etiam sed leo id mi rhoncus luctus a nec mauris.
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).